# Contract Function calling storage contract not setting value correctly

Tags: contract-development

so i have a storage Contract A which has the following mapping and function.

```
mapping (address => mapping (bytes32 => uint8)) addressToQueryIDToStatus; // 0=no init, 1=init, 2=fail, 3=succeed, auth written, 4=retrieved.
mapping (bytes32 => address) queryIDToAddress; //

function requestAuthorization(bytes32 _queryID, address _sender)
public restricted(msg.sender)
{
    require(_sender != address(0x0));
    require(_queryID[0] != 0);
    addressToQueryIDToStatus[_sender][_queryID] = 1;
    queryIDToAddress[_queryID] = _sender;
    emit LogStorageEventRequestAuthorization("requestAuthorization", _queryID, _sender);
}
```

which works fine by it self it testing.

I have a second contract B that calls contract A through an interface function below. (i have several of these functions working correctly, but this one has me stumped)

```
    function requestAuthorization(bytes32 _queryID, address _sender) external;
```

calling function:

```
function requestAuthorization(bytes32 _level, string _input)
public whenNotPaused //IDContractOnly(msg.sender)
returns(bytes32)  
{    
    //require(_level.length > 0, "A");  
    //require(bytes(_input).length > 0,"B");  
    bytes32 queryId = "1";  
   CoinIDStorageInterface(coinIDStorageAddress).requestAuthorization(queryId, msg.sender);
    emit LogNewOraclizeQuery2("Oraclize query with was sent, standing by for the answer for input.. ", msg.sender, queryId, _level, _input);
    return (queryId);
}
```

with the following test code:

```
    // this works
    //await coinIDStorageContract.requestAuthorization("1", accounts[1], {from: fromOwner});
    // this doesn't seem to get to storage.
    console.log("Request Auth CoinIDBankContract");
    await coinIDBankContract.requestAuthorization("1", "2085551212", {from: accounts[1]});

    //console.log(returnedQueryID);
    let queryStateCheck = await coinIDStorageContract.requestAuthorizationState("1", accounts[1], {from: fromOwner});
    console.log("CoinIDStorage AuthState: " + queryStateCheck.toNumber());
    //console.log(queryStateCheck)
    let queryState2 = await coinIDBankContract.requestAuthorizationState("1", accounts[1], {from: accounts[1]});

    console.log("CoinIDBank AuthState: " + queryState2);
    assert.equal (queryState2.toNumber(), "1",  "Bank Request of Query State incorrect, should be 1");
```

with the following results:

```
CoinIDStorage AuthState: 0
CoinIDBank QueryState: 0
1) CoinIDBank: Auth Request

Events emitted during test:
---------------------------

LogStorageEventRequestAuthorization(functionName: requestAuthorization, _queryID: 0x3100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, _sender: 0x839c18df17236382f8832d9ab5ef3facafbac891)
LogNewOraclizeQuery2(description: Oraclize query with was sent, standing by for the answer for input.. , _sender: 0x839c18df17236382f8832d9ab5ef3facafbac891, queryId: 0x3100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, level: 0x1000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000, input: 2085551212)
```

So it looks like i have the right values passing, don't get any errors or reverts, and the emits have the right values, HOWEVER, when i check the value, which now should be 1, all i get is the un-itialized 0 state back.  If i use the first commented out command, it definitely gets set, and returns the state of 1 which is the intended effect.

Probably something small, but i just don't see it.

this function sets the same value and works in both cases.

```
    await coinIDStorageContract.returnAuthorizationFail("1", {from: fromOwner});  
    await coinIDBankContract.returnAuthorizationFail("1", {from: fromOwner});
```

returning-

```
CoinIDStorage AuthState: 2
CoinIDBank AuthState: 2
```

which is correct... still can't see the hangup...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the testing.  I wasn't sending in the same values at each step.

Once I put a 'web3.fromAcii("1") in each spot it worked correctly.  I knew it was something small.